# Convergence to $\ln(n)$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Is there any hint for $\,\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!\!\!\frac{n\cos x}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\;$?

I've tried with $n \approx 9000000000000000000$ and find that it seems to converge to $\ln(n)$ but no clue to prove that.

E.g. $n=9000000000000000000$, the integral is $44.2316884183270$ (while $\ln(n) = 43.6437562512290$). $n=90000000000000000$, the integral is $39.6265182323389$ (while $\ln(n) = 39.0385860652409$)

Comment: Any theorem. Actually I've tried first to prove that the limit is infinity (but not success)

Comment: What do you mean by "converge to $\ln(n)$"? Can you edit your post present the result of your "try with $n \approx 9000000000000000000$"? What you mean by that is not clear either. And how did this "try" make you think "the limit is infinity"?

Comment: @TaThanhDinh Do you mean by "converges to $\log n$"? You are taking the limit in $n$... In case of convergence,  you'll get a number.

Comment: It seems that $\,\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!\!\!\frac{n\cos x}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}\,\mathrm dx-\ln n\right)=l\in\Bbb R^+.$ Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I_n:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{n\cos x}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=J_n-K_n$$ where $$J_n:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1{n^2}}}=\sinh^{-1}\frac{n\pi}2=\ln n+\ln\left(\frac\pi2+\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+\frac{\pi^2}4}\right)$$
and (by dominated convergence)
$$K_n:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1{n^2}}}\,\mathrm dx\longrightarrow K:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos x}x\,\mathrm dx$$
([$=-{\rm Ci}\frac\pi2+\gamma+\ln\frac\pi2\approx0.5568$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Ccos+x%7Dx+dx+from+x%3D0+to+pi%2F2))
hence
$$I_n-\ln n\longrightarrow-K+\ln\pi$$
($={\rm Ci}\frac\pi2-\gamma+\ln2$ [$\approx0.588$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Ci%28%5Cpi%2F2%29-%5Cgamma%2B%5Cln%282%29)).

Answer (score 6):

Let's denote $\displaystyle I(n)=n\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}dx$.

Then, integrating by part,
$$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}dx=\cos x\ln\left(x+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}\,\right)\,\bigg|_0^\frac\pi2+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln\left(x+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}\,\right)\sin x\,dx$$
The second term converges at $n\to\infty$. Therefore, with the accuracy up to $o(1)$,
$$I(n)=\ln n+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2x)\sin x\,dx+o(1)=\ln n+\ln 2+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln x \,\sin x\,dx+o(1)$$
$$=\ln n+\ln 2-\gamma+\operatorname{Ci}\big(\frac\pi2\big)+o(1)$$

*Numeric check with WolframAlpha*
$\displaystyle n=100 \quad I(100)=\color{blue}{5.193}\,241...\qquad \ln (100)+\ln 2+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln x \,\sin x\,dx=\color{blue}{5.193}\,102... $

---

With some additional efforts next asymptotic terms can be found:
$$I(n)=n\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}dx=\ln n+\ln 2+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln x\,\sin x\,dx$$
$$+\frac{1}{4n^2}\Big(\ln n+\ln2+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln x\,\sin x\,dx+1-\frac{2}{\pi}\Big)+o\big(\frac{1}{n^2}\big)$$
*Numeric check with WolframAlpha*

$\displaystyle n=100 \quad I(100)=\color{blue}{5.193\,241\,26}6\,17...\quad \text{approximation}=\color{blue}{5.193\,241\,26}5\,15... $

Comment: congrats for hitting 10k :)

Comment: @Sine of the Time Thank you! :)